# How to copy war file into a particular destination using batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, command

```
SET src="C:/Users/Neonous/Desktop/New folder/Package/Project-1.war"
SET dest="C:/Program Files/Apache/webapps"
xcopy %src% %dest% /E
```

I tried the above script to copy war file. its extracting and creating some unwanted directories in to the destination location.
i want to copy the zipped file.... as such Project-1.war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple :**

```
 copy %src% %dest%\Project-1.war
```

I don't know why you want to use `xcopy` if you want to copy the file only.
If you want to do something else please specify.

Also use backslash" \ " to separate directories and specify file name for targeted destination.

Hope this helped,

Yours Mona.

Comment: Xcopy would have worked without the /E and please note that when using the copy command you only need to specify the target name if you are **changing** the target filename.